# Releasing connection: Connection can be kept alive indefinitely in tomcat while sending request from one form to another

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, amazon-web-services, jotform

I am using 2 forms in my application. From my first form I am taking form data to servlet class and from this servlet by passing URL of second from I am redirecting to my second form.

I am using this in my code:

```
Response.sendRedirect("[next form url]");
```

My application is web application written in java. I have deployed my application in tomcat running locally. Everything is fine till here. I am getting response as excepted.

But, problem is when I am deploying my application on tomcat running on AWS machine. It is able to fetch data from form1 to servlet and redirect to next form say "form2". But after the it is closing connection giving this message.

```
2015-02-03 08:06:01 DEBUG BasicClientConnectionManager:196 - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@1a419e99
2015-02-03 08:06:01 DEBUG BasicClientConnectionManager:221
```

Connection can be kept alive indefinitely and not excepting any data from second "form2". May I know the reason and how to solve this.

Comment: what's the keep alive time? i.e. for IE its one minute..

Comment: This piece of code is actually getting called from the releaseConnection() method in BasicClientConnectionManager. So the first question is why the releaseConnection()  getting called? Do you have any exception handlers present(try catch) in your servlet and seeing any errors?